# MyClass.class if MyClass is generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a piece of code which does not compile:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

  private <T> Optional<T> g(
      Class<T> typeClass) {
    throw new RuntimeException("???");
  }

  private void f() {
    Optional<Optional<Integer>> x;
    x = g(Optional.class);
  }
}
```

Compiler says that g(Optional.class) is wrong, because:

`incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints Optional<Integer>,Optional`

I alse tried passing `Optional<Integer>.class`, but it also does not compile - as far as I understand, this is an illegal syntax.

So, what argument should I pass to g() so this example compiles?

Comment: @experiment unit 1998X : I don't understand you.

Comment: You must see this before asking question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question isn't telling what is your actual problem, what you want to achieve. If you change your g method to this - g(Class<?> typeClass), it will work but you must know where to use ? and T and that all depends on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in order to call g() we must have an object of type `Class<Optional<Integer>>`. We can get this object in this way, for instance:

```
x = g((Class<Optional<Integer>>) Optional.empty().getClass());
```

And this is a solution of the problem.